# Get browser locale code in Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a Firefox add-on. I need to determine which language is set in the user's browser.
Is there some kind of object like `window.navigator`, which contains the browser's current locale?

Comment: What [kind of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) are you making ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), [Bootstraped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), or [Overlay/XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions))? Please [edit] the appropriate tag into your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Methods to access the locale

**Use `window.navigator`:**
While there may be something else, you could just use [`window.navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator).

The [`navigator` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) may only be available on the `window` object associated with content (i.e. not the one that is the browser's XUL `window`). However, even if you need to access it from a content script, the object is available to all extension types.

- [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) : You will need to access it from a content script.
- All other types: You can access `window.navigator` from your main/background script even in multiprocess Firefox. As always in an extension, you have to use the correct `<window>` object.  Not all `<window>` objects have a `navigator` property.

**Get the Firefox preference:**
However, one appears to be the preference `general.useragent.locale`, or perhaps `intl.accept_languages`. What type of add-on you are writing will determine how you could access this, or even if it is currently available:

- [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) extensions can access them using [`preferences/service`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service).
- [Bootstrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) or [legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) add-ons can use [`Services.prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm), which gives you access to [nsIPrefBranch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch), [nsIPrefBranch2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch2), and [nsIPrefService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefService).
- At this time, [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) do not appear to have access to preferences. Given how integral preferences are to Firefox, they will probably be available in the future.

**Use `getLocale()` on a ChromeWindow:**
As mentioned by stkvtflw, you can also use `getLocale()` on the main ChromeWindow. The [PanelUI](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/customizableui/content/panelUI.js) (not to be confused with [sdk/panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel)) includes a function [`getLocale()`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/components/customizableui/content/panelUI.js#522). However, there does not appear to be any official documentation for this function. The code for it is:

```
function getLocale() {
  try {
    let chromeRegistry = Cc["@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1"]
                           .getService(Ci.nsIXULChromeRegistry);
    return chromeRegistry.getSelectedLocale("browser");
  } catch (ex) {
    return "en-US";
  }
}
```

Obviously, this indicates you could use the `nsIXULChromeRegistry` service directly, should you desire. There also does not appear to be official documentation for this service.

**WebExtensions specific method:**
WebExtensions has the [Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Internationalization), which is available from background scripts. The local is available using [`i18n.getUILanguage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/I18n/getUILanguage). The method [`i18n.getAcceptLanguages()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/i18n/getAcceptLanguages) may also be of interest.

### Complete code for WebExtensions add-ons

*main.js*

```js
let locale = chrome.i18n.getUILanguage();
console.log('The locale is: ' + locale);
```

*manifest.json*

```json
{
    "description": "Log the locale to the console",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "log_locale",
    "version": "0.1",
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "extention@stick.man",
            "strict_min_version": "45.0"
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
}
```

### Complete code for Add-on SDK extensions

*index.js*:

```js
//Get the window.navigator from current window/tab

//Get the currently active Browser Window
let activeWindow = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
//activeWindow.document.defaultView is the <window> you want to use
let defaultViewNavigator = activeWindow.document.defaultView.navigator;
//log the language from window.navigator
console.log('navigator language='+defaultViewNavigator.language);


//Get the locale from preferences:
let prefs = require("sdk/preferences/service");
let langFromPref = prefs.get(`general.useragent.locale`);
console.log('language from prefs='+langFromPref);


//Get the locale using getLocale():
let localeGet = require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow().getLocale()
console.log('getLocale language='+localeGet);
```

*package.json*:

```json
{
  "title": "Find locale",
  "name": "find_local",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Find the locale",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Makyen",
  "engines": {
    "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
    "fennec": ">=38.0a1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "jetpack"
  ]
}
```

### Code for bootstrap/legacy add-ons

```js
//Import Services
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
//Get the currently active Browser Window
let activeWindow=Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");

//Get the window.navigator from current window/tab   
//activeWindow.document.defaultView is the <window> you want to use
let defaultViewNavigator = activeWindow.document.defaultView.navigator;
console.log('navigator language='+defaultViewNavigator.language);

//Get the locale from preferences:
let langFromPref = Services.prefs.getCharPref(`general.useragent.locale`);
console.log('language from prefs='+langFromPref);

//Get the locale using getLocale():
let localeGet = activeWindow.getLocale()
console.log('getLocale language='+localeGet);
```

Comment: It's Add-on SDK. Sorry, i don't get it, how exactly i can access locale using `preferences/service`? I've imported `sdk/preferences/service`, but which prop should i request from it?

Comment: also, i've tryed `window.navigator` it's not defined event if i'm requesting it in `index.js`.

Comment: @stkvtflw, The reason that `window.navigator` did not work for you was either you did not define `window`, or you pointed `window` at the wrong `<window>`.  One of the things most confused by people starting out with extensions, and Firefox extensions in particular, is the need to set `window` to the correct `<window>` for whatever it is that they are attempting to accomplish. From an add-on's point of view there are a lot of `<window>` object which could be used. This is *very* different from the single `window` which is defined for scripts on webpages.

Comment: @stkvtflw, I updated this with a bit more description and tested code for all types of Firefox add-ons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i've solved this slightly simpler: `require("sdk/window/utils").getMostRecentBrowserWindow().getLocale()` - that's all.

Comment: @stkvtflw, I added `getLocale()` to the answer and code.  However, I did not find any documentation on it. I can see it when looking through the properties available on a ChromeWindow, and find it in the source code, but have not found any official documentation.  What documentation did you find (link please)? How did you find this method?

Comment: i haven't found any docs on it) just logged the object and noticed this method in it)

Comment: @stkvtflw, Darn. I was hoping for some docs. I also did that (log using [`console.dir(activeWindow)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir). In addition, I took a look at it in the [DOM Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/), accessed from the main`<document>.defaultView.getLocale()`.

Comment: unfortunately, this is one more proof that firefox add-ons sdk sucks in various ways, including it's documentation

Answer (score 2):

@Mayken's answer is excellent. I just want to add though, you can also get `navigator` without `window`, you can do so with `WebWorker`s or `ChromeWorker`s they have a bunch of useful stuff available:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers#workerscope

I wouldn't recommend launching a worker just to get navigator info, it would be probably be easier to use `Services.appshell.hiddenDOMWindow`, but if you are using workers already, then yes its a nice solution.

Comment: The page you linked explicitly states that [`WorkerNavigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerNavigator) does not support [`NavigatorLanguage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage). However, the WorkerNavigator page says that [`NavigatorLanguage.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) is available. Have you tested it. If so, lets change the "Functions and classes available to Web Workers" page to say partial support, not "*No support*" (in red text).

Comment: Thanks @Mayken for that catch. I didn't know the docs said that. I tested it just now and it seems it is fully available - http://i.imgur.com/mEqovfM.png - can you please verify from my screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for testing that, @Noitidart. It looks like it's supported to me.  I changed it on the MDN page, [Functions and classes available to Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers#APIs_available_in_workers), from `{{CompatNo}}` to `{{CompatVersionUnknown}}`

Comment: Thanks so much @Mayken! If I figure out the version number I'll update it with that and let you know.